# Git Merging a whole repository a folder of another

Tags: git

Hopefully an interesting question, i'm using git for source control and i have the need to merge a whole repository ( that i don't have write access to ) into another repository that i do, but i want to place it into a nested folder.

```
'.\X -> .\Y\X'
```

I need to retain all the history of the source repository as i'll be continuing to pull updates.

I've spent a while looking at this but to no avail.

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you look at git submodules? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: Yes, i did, however, I want to be able to push changes i make to .\Y\X to my respository, but never push back in to the remote effectively .\X

Comment: I don't think you can save edits to .\Y\X into the Y repository and keep X as a separate repository.. can you fork the .\X repository?

Comment: Yup i have that ability.

Comment: Then probably you can fork Y and put the fork as a submodule in .\Y\forkedX. you can push your changes to forkedX and merge into forkedX the updates from original X. does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah so effectively having 2 repositories linked together via submodule. Allowing me to commit from one setup using the same gui and retain the tree information for both?